# How to make a class/object that can be referenced at multiple levels

Tags: javascript, class, object

I have read many, many ways of making makeshift classes in javascript. I'm trying to create a giant list of items, each with a variety of variables. I need to be able to call a certain object's properties from this list.
The following code compiles, but when line 9 tries to access items.yspeed1.name, it creates the button with the name "undefined". I have no clue how to access a function's variables in javascript like this.

```
var itemslist = function(){
    this.yspeed1 = function(){
        this.name = 'Yellow Upgrade';
        this.price = 50;
    }
    this.yspeed2 = function(){
        this.name = 'Blue Upgrade';
        this.price = 25;
    }
}

var newitem = document.createElement('button');
newitem.innerHTML = items.yspeed1.name;
shop.appendChild(newitem);
```

Comment: I don't see you calling itemslist class/function anywhere in your code

Comment: Where is the code for populating `items`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a class in JS when you are defining a reusable structure with state, i.e. you might have multiple copies (instances) of a class.

What you have is just a definition of a single object (single instance) with properties.  So use that Javascript construct instead:

```
var itemslist = {
    yspeed1: {
        name: 'Yellow Upgrade'
        , price: 50
    }
    , yspeed2: {
        name: 'Blue Upgrade'
        , price:  25
    }
}
```

Now you have a single object with two properties -- yspeed1 and yspeed2.  And those each have their own properties of name and price.

If you want to expand that object, just add to it, e.g. `itemslist.yspeed3 = { hello: 'world' };`

Comment: This works perfectly for what I was trying to do. I didn't know it was possible without using a function.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for a starters `yspeed1` is a `function` so you have to call it anyway, I think this might be the sort of thing you're looking for.

```
var itemslist = function(){
    this.yspeed1 = {
        name: 'Yellow Upgrade',
        price: 50
    }
}
```

This is just one way. other than that you'll have to create a

```
new items.yspeed1();
```

Comment: Similarly, he's not `new`'ing an isntance of itemslist, so this change alone won't even fix his issue.  Your example of creating new `yspeed1` also needs to apply to the initial object he's trying to reference.

Comment: And what's the initial object? I don't get it.

Comment: `newitem.innerHTML = items.yspeed1.name;` my bad.  here he's accessing `items` not `itemslist` so I guess we can assume he's already `new`'d it.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

There are situations where "classes" are useful, but I think you can get away with a simple object here.

```
var items = {}
items.yspeed1 = {}
items.yspeed1.name = 'Yellow Upgrade';
items.yspeed1.price = 50;
items.yspeed2 = {};
items.yspeed2.name = 'Blue Upgrade';
items.yspeed2.price = 25;

var newitem = document.createElement('button');
newitem.innerHTML = items.yspeed1.name;
shop.appendChild(newitem);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your looking to use a class based approach here's one using prototypes

Item Class:

```
function YSpeedItem(name, price)
{
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
}

YSpeedItem.prototype.getName = function()
{
  return this.name;
}

YSpeedItem.prototype.getPrice = function()
{
  return this.price;
}`
```

main code

```
var yspeed1 = new YSpeedItem("Yellow Upgrade", 50);
var yspeed2 = new YSpeedItem("Blue Upgrade", 25);
itemsList = [];
itemsList.push(yspeed1);
itemsList.push(yspeed2);

var newitem = document.createElement('button');
newitem.innerHTML = items[0].getName;
shop.appendChild(newitem);
```

more info here http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/